# Why do we use malloc in linkedlist while inserting a node?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // WHY this?
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

Comment: DMA doesn't stand for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: If you don't use dynamic memory allocation, where will you get the memory for each node? You can't use a local variable because it goes away when the function returns.

Comment: @Amit Kumar What is the problem? If you do not want to use malloc then do not use it.

Comment: How do you think it should be written without malloc?

Comment: @user253751 For example using an array.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but how does Amit Kumar think it should be written without malloc?

Comment: @user253751 One way I already wrote in a comment above.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow To repeat: I don't want to know how YOU think it should be written, but how the question author thinks it should be written.

Comment: @user253751 For starters I did not say how the list should be written. I said that it can be implemented for example using an array. As for the author of the question I do not know how he thinks it should be implemented. He is free to select any approach.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I do not understand your point here... you tell me how you think it should be written, then you tell me you were not actually telling me that.

Comment: @user253751 May I leave you with your fantasies alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about lifetime of objects.

The C standard describes this as "storage duration". The 3 most common types are

1. automatic storage duration
2. allocated storage duration
3. static storage duration

The lifetime of objects with automatic storage duration is limited to the block where the object is defined. For instance a variable defined in a function will only exist inside the function. So if you did

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    
    struct Node new_node;         // new_node has automatic storage duration
                                  // so it only exist within this function
    new_node.data = new_data;
    new_node.next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = &new_node;      // Very bad... never do this
}
```

you would end up in a situation where `*head_ref` points to a dead object.

So for a linked list, you just can't use a local variable.

The lifetime of objects with allocated storage duration is from `malloc` (or friends) return and until your code explicit kills the object by calling `free`. That is exactly what you would want for a linked list. An object where you can control it's lifetime.

Notice: when you do

```
struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

there are two objects in play. `new_node` itself is still an object with automatic storage duration (and will only exist inside the function) but it's value (i.e. the value returned by `malloc`) is a pointer to a node object with allocated storage duration. Therefore you can save the value of `new_node` in the linked list and have a pointer to an object that still exist when the function returns.

The lifetime of objects with static storage duration is from program start to program end. So such objects can be used for linked lists. You can write a program with a pool of static nodes and whenever you need a new node in the linked list, you can take a node from that pool. It's doable but will require extra code to maintain the pool of available nodes (i.e. kind of implementing your own version of Node-malloc/Node-free). Another downside is that it limits the max length of your list to a fixed number (i.e. to the number of static node objects in the pool at start-up).

So using objects with allocated storage duration is by far the simplest approach. When you need a new node just call `malloc`. When you are done with a node just call `free`.

In some special cases you may go for a pool of objects with static storage duration.